# SQL error: near ".2016": syntax error

Tags: c++, time, sqlite, buffer, strftime

```
struct tm* tm_info;   
struct timeval tv;   
gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);   
tm_info = localtime(&tv.tv_sec);   
strftime(buffer, 33, "%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M", tm_info);   
printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

...

```
sql=(char*)malloc(sizeof("INSERT into MESSAGES(from_user,to_user,time_sent,message) values('")+30+sizeof("','")+30+sizeof("',")+100+sizeof(",' ")+500+sizeof(" ')"));
strcpy(sql,"INSERT into MESSAGES(from_user,to_user,time_sent,message) values('");
strcat(sql,login);
strcat(sql,"','");
strcat(sql,nume_cu_cine_vb);
strcat(sql,"',");
strcat(sql,buffer);
strcat(sql,",' ");
strcat(sql,array);
strcat(sql," ')");
 rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, nothing_to_do_query, 0, &zErrMsg);      
 **if( rc != SQLITE_OK ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "SQL error1: %s\n",zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg); }**
```

Here is the error1.. near ".2016": syntax error while i am running the code (the error is in server).
I don`t know what to do.. Help me if you know & thanks.

Comment: Try `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` or `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` as your `strftime` format string.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the final query string you generate you should easily see the problem. It looks like this:

```
INSERT into MESSAGES(from_user,to_user,time_sent,message) values('aaa','bbb',10.02.2016, 10:59,' ccc ')
```

You'll notice that the date-time is added as is, without quotes, which completely messes up the query. It should probably look like this instead:

```
INSERT into MESSAGES(from_user,to_user,time_sent,message) values('aaa','bbb', '10.02.2016, 10:59',' ccc ')
```

Notice the quotes around the full date. These will make it a single field and make the query look valid. Now for MySQL to actually recognize and be able to parse that datetime you should also put it in [a valid format](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), for example YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS instead of the custom one you're using.
So the final field value should look something like this:

```
'2016-02-10 10:54:12'
```

and the generated query should look like:

```
INSERT into MESSAGES(from_user,to_user,time_sent,message) values('aaa','bbb', '2016-02-10 10:54:12',' ccc ')
```